# Volume of $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying both $\prod_{i=1}^n {x_i}^2 < \alpha$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n {x_i}^2 < \beta$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, indefinite-integrals

I want to find the volume of the $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying both ${x_1}^2 \cdot {x_2}^2 \cdot \ldots \cdot {x_n}^2 < \alpha$ and ${x_1}^2 + {x_2}^2 +\ldots + {x_n}^2 < \beta$. I can solve this easily for $n=2$, and possibly $n=3$ with some effort, but I'm not sure how to get an analytic solution in general? If an analytic solution is too hard, then it'd be helpful to know whatever can be said about the scaling of this volume with $n$, $\alpha$, and $\beta$. Thank you!

Comment: The analytic solution exists. It suffices to generalize the solution for the case $n = 3$. The volume is equal to the volume of the sphere substracting $2^n$ equal parts.

Comment: @NN2 Thank you! Do you think you could expand on that a little? I realize that you can divide the integral into parts by symmetry, but how do you calculate the solution on those individual parts?